# .commy Ajax call doesn't work in my domain

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here's my code.
I think it has an error in my path.
It's my first time putting AJAX in a domain...

```
    $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.komatpillar.com/ajax/check_email.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {pass_email_address : email_address},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                var res = result.user_id;
                if(res > 0){

                    $('#message_email').focus(); 
                    window.scrollTo(0, 540);
                    $('#danger_container_email').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger');
                    $('#message_email').html('This email address is already existing!');
                    $('#register').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#register').removeAttr('name');
                    $('#message').css('color', 'red');
                    $('#success_email').attr('class','form-group has-error has-feedback');
                    $('#email_glyp').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback');


                    }else{
                            $('#danger_container_email').removeAttr('class');
                            $('#message_email').html('');
                            $('#success_email').attr('class','row form-group has-success has-feedback');
                            $('#email_glyp').attr('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback');
                            $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
                            $('#register').attr('name','cmd_add_new_user');

                        }
```

Here's the rest of it.

Comment: What error do you see? 404?

Comment: @hamed it has no error.. I think the path doesn't work... but I check the path and put an echo msg and it displays...

Comment: @user3113490 did you check the console log? The error might have been displayed there.

Comment: If the echo message displays, this means the ajax path is correct. I think the problem can be inside `check_email.php` file.

Comment: @hamed I've tried it on local and works just fine.

Comment: if dataType : 'json' fails to parse correctly the success function will not get called. First remove the "dataType:'json'," line. This will let ajax try to determine the type. Second in the success function alert or log the result var.

Comment: @bassxzero I tried omitting the json... still doesn't work.

Comment: @user3113490 are you getting output in the success function?

Comment: @no output return... it goes to my else code... though

Comment: @user3113490 can we see the rest of the code?

Comment: @bassxzero I also tried alerting the email_address.. and it alerts... maybe the JSON has problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74986/discussion-between-bassxzero-and-user3113490).

Answer (score -1):

Change this :

```
  data: {pass_email_address : email_address},
```

to this:

```
  data: "{pass_email_address:'" + email_address + "'}",
```

Comment: I'll try sir. but you think the problem is not on the URL path?

Comment: @user3113490 by using FireBug, can you put breakpoint to each of these lines starting with `url`, `type`, `data`, and `dataType` and see if it gets `success` line?

Comment: @user3113490 put a break also to this line `var res = result.user_id;`, and mouse over the `result` in this line ` function(result) {` and please share what you see?